# Is there a way to play Twitch Streams inside Android app (Java)

Tags: java, android, webview, twitch

I am unable to play Twitch Streams in my Android application.
Twitch is only providing their embed url for playing Streams.

I am using this url:  https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=CHANNEL_NAME

I am using a WebView to load this url by

```
mWebview.loadUrl(url);
```

But this method has several issues, like the video tends to autoplay but gets stuck initially. I need to press *Pause* first and then the *Play* button to start this stream.

Comment: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference#get-streams

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code.

```
  private WebView mWebview ;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    mWebview  = new WebView(this);

    mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

    final Activity activity = this;

    mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @TargetApi(android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest req, WebResourceError rerr) {
            // Redirect to deprecated method, so you can use it in all SDK versions
            onReceivedError(view, rerr.getErrorCode(), rerr.getDescription().toString(), req.getUrl().toString());
        }
    });

    mWebview .loadUrl(url);
    setContentView(mWebview );

}
```